# How to save in database a new input field?

Tags: php, html, laravel

So, I have a function which can fill my column from database with value 1 at click, and now I added a input field, and I need to save the text from the new input in column `decline_reason.`

**Here is what I have tried to do:**

```
public function cancelp(requ $request, $id)
{
        Reports::find($id)->update(['status' => '0']);
        Reports::find($id)->update(['decline_reason' => $request['decline_reason']]);
        Session::flash('message', "Report declined");
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

Now

**My view with button who fill my column with value 1**

```
 <div class="modal-body">
       <label>Specify the reason</label>
  <input name="decline_reason" class="form-control" type="text"/>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <a>{{ link_to('admin/reports/p/' . $report->id. '/action-cancel', 'Decline', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) }}</a>
     </div>
```

`Route::get('admin/reports/p/{job}/action-cancel', 'ArticleController@cancelp');`

**Reports model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reports extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reports';

    // public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'username', 'user_id_posted', 'username_posted', 'news_id','opinion_id','event_id','career_solution_id', 'subject', 'why_reporting','why_reporting_message','additional_message','status', 'comment_id', 'decline_reason'
    ];


    public function career_solutionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareerSolution','career_solution_id','id');
    }
     public function eventReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event','event_id','id');
    }
     public function newsReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News','news_id','id');
    }
     public function opinionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Opinion','opinion_id','id');
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

For the moment, the column is `null` in database.

Comment: Please can you share your `Reports` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a>{{ link_to('admin/reports/p/' . $report->id. '/decline', 'Decline', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) }}</a>

Route::get('admin/reports/p/{job}/{action}', 'ArticleController@cancelp');
```

Change your update code

```
public function cancelp($job,$action)
{
        Reports::find($job)->update(['status' => '0','decline_reason' => $action]);
        Session::flash('message', "Report declined");
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

**Note**: Make sure your **Reports** model has fillable value of `status,decline_reason`

```
class Reportsextends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'status', 'decline_reason'
    ];
}
```

**As if you want to pass it with the input feild.**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('report.submit') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="{{ $report->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="decline_reason" value="decline">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Submit">

    </button>
</form>
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('admin/reports/submit', 'ArticleController@canclesubmit')->name('report.submit');
```

**Controller**

```
public function canclesubmit(requ $request)
{
        Reports::find($request->job_id)->update(['status' => '0','decline_reason' => $request->decline_reason]);
        Session::flash('message', "Report declined");
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still not saving in database :( Only status.

Comment: It because of you're passing get method and Request instance for post method. I updated my answer check and try to make this type of request in parameter.

Comment: I updated my code, but now in column `decline_reason` I get only `decline`, not the text from my input :( Do you know why?

Comment: `<a>{{ link_to('admin/reports/p/' . $report->id. '/decline', 'Decline', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) }}</a>` in this url pass it as you want. I passed `' . $report->id. '/decline'` decline here that's why status updated as decline you pass as you want.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I get it.Can I save the value from `<input name="decline_reason" class="form-control" type="text"/>` instead of decline from this link? Because I need to save the text in database.That's the last step, without this, all is working fine.

Comment: So you need to pass it in form with post method. Let me edit my as for post method.

Comment: Edited please check it. it's an simple submit form as you expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199915/discussion-between-andrew-and-laravel).